# Solving 2 Non-Linear Equations

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I've been working with this equations of Potential Flow

pSI:  0 = 10 * y + 23.8732414638 * (pi + atan(abs((x - 12) / x))) + 23.8732414638 * (pi - atan(abs((y + 12) / x)))-234.882642242

V: 0 = ((10 + 23.8732414638 * x / (x**2 + (y - 12)**2) + 23.8732414638 * x / (x**2 + (y + 12)**2))**2 + (23.8732414638 * (y - 12) / (x**2 + (y - 12)**2) + 23.8732414638 * (y + 12) / (x**2 + (y + 12)**2))**2)**0.5-8

using the next code to solve them:

```
# Prototype of N-R for a system of two non-linear equations
# evaluating  functions of two variables
from math import *
eq1 = raw_input('Enter the equation 1: ')
eq2 = raw_input('Enter the equation 2: ')
x0 = float(input('Enter x: '))
y0 = float(input('Enter y: '))

def f(x,y):
    return eval(eq1)

def g(x,y):
    return eval(eq2)

x = x0
y = y0

for n in range(1, 8):

    a = (f(x + 1e-06, y) - f(x,y)) / 1e-06
    b = (f(x, y + 1e-06) - f(x,y)) / 1e-06
    c =  - f(x,y)
    d = (g(x + 1e-06, y) - g(x,y)) / 1e-06
    eE = (g(x, y + 1e-06) - g(x,y)) / 1e-06
    fF =  - g(x,y)

    print "f(x, y)= ", eq1
    print "g(x, y)= ", eq2
    print """x   y """
    print x, y
    print """a   b   c   d   e   f """
    print a, b, c, d, e, fF

    print """
    a * x + b * y = c
    d * x + e * y = f
    """

    print a," * x  +  ",b," * y  =  ",c
    print d," * x  +  ",eE," * y  =  ",fF

    _Sy = (c - a * fF / d) / (b - a * eE / d)
    _Sx = (fF / d) - (eE / d) * _Sy

    Ea_X = (_Sx ** 2 + _Sy ** 2)**0.5

    x = x + _Sx
    y = y + _Sy

    print "Sx = ", _Sx
    print "Sy = ", _Sy

    print "x = ", x
    print "y = ", y

    print "|X_1 - X_0| = ", Ea_X
```

And gives me the Zero division Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Principal\Mis documentos\Finished_Non_lin_N_R.py", line 38, in <module>
    d = (g(x + 1e-06, y) - g(x,y)) / 1e-06
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Principal\Mis documentos\Finished_Non_lin_N_R.py", line 27, in g
    return eval(eq2)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Then I tried with this one that I've found in one solved question:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from math import *

def equations(p):
    x, y = p
    return ( ((10 + 23.8732414638 * x / (x**2 + (y - 12)**2) + 23.8732414638 * x / (x**2 + (y + 12)**2))**2 + (23.8732414638 * (y -12) / (x**2 + (y - 12)**2) + 23.8732414638 * (y + 12) / (x**2 + (y + 12)**2))**2)**0.5-8, 10 * y + 23.8732414638 * (pi + atan(abs((x - 12) / x))) + 23.8732414638 * (pi - atan(abs((y + 12) / x)))-234.882642242)

x, y =  fsolve(equations, (0, 18))

print equations((x, y))
```

And with the next problem:

```
<module2>:19: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in long_scalars
<module2>:19: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
(-1.3374190643844486e-11, -2.8308022592682391e-11)
```

And the last part of this story is that I have some code that actually works
but is too clumsy and a little bit inaccurate, and I would like some suggestions in order to make it simple:

```
from math import *
U = 10
b = 15
h = 12

cF = 0.5 * U * b / pi

pSI0 = 234.882642242
VP = 12.0

X0 = 0
Y0 = 40

sX = 0.01
sY = 0.01

print cF

def FirstFor(A,B,C,D):
    for n in range(1,808):
        for m in range(1,4002):
            X = A - B*n
            Y = C - D*m

            pSI = U * Y + cF * (pi + atan(abs((Y - h) / X))) + cF * (pi - atan(abs((Y + h) / X)))
            Vaprox = ((10 + 23.8732414638 * X / (X**2 + (Y - 12)**2) + 23.8732414638 * X / (X**2 + (Y + 12)**2))**2 +(23.8732414638 * (Y - 12) / (X**2 + (Y - 12)**2) + 23.8732414638 * (Y + 12) / (X**2 + (Y + 12)**2))**2)**0.5

            EA1 = abs(pSI0 - pSI)
            EA2 = abs(VP - Vaprox)

            if EA1 < 0.05 and EA2 < 0.05:
                X1f = X
                Y1f = Y
                H3 = [X1f,Y1f]
                print n,m,X,Y,"GG son",EA1,EA2
                print H3

    for n in range(1,808):
        for m in range(1,4002):
            X = H3[0] - B*n*0.001
            Y = H3[1] - D*m*0.001

            pSI = U * Y + cF * (pi + atan(abs((Y - h) / X))) + cF * (pi - atan(abs((Y + h) / X)))
            Vaprox = ((10 + 23.8732414638 * X / (X**2 + (Y - 12)**2) + 23.8732414638 * X / (X**2 + (Y + 12)**2))**2 +(23.8732414638 * (Y - 12) / (X**2 + (Y - 12)**2) + 23.8732414638 * (Y + 12) / (X**2 + (Y + 12)**2))**2)**0.5

            EA1 = abs(pSI0 - pSI)
            EA2 = abs(VP - Vaprox)

            if EA1 < 0.0001 and EA2 < 0.0001:
                X2f = X
                Y2f = Y
                I3 = [X2f,Y2f]
                print n,m,X,Y,"GG son",EA1,EA2
                print I3


    for n in range(1,808):
        for m in range(1,4002):
            X = H3[0] + B*n*0.001
            Y = H3[1] + D*m*0.001

            pSI = U * Y + cF * (pi + atan(abs((Y - h) / X))) + cF * (pi - atan(abs((Y + h) / X)))
            Vaprox = ((10 + 23.8732414638 * X / (X**2 + (Y - 12)**2) + 23.8732414638 * X / (X**2 + (Y + 12)**2))**2 +(23.8732414638 * (Y - 12) / (X**2 + (Y - 12)**2) + 23.8732414638 * (Y + 12) / (X**2 + (Y + 12)**2))**2)**0.5

            EA1 = abs(pSI0 - pSI)
            EA2 = abs(VP - Vaprox)

            if EA1 < 0.0001 and EA2 < 0.0001:
                X2f = X
                Y2f = Y
                I3 = [X2f,Y2f]
                print n,m,X,Y,"GG son",EA1,EA2
                print I3


# starting with the FirstFor
FirstFor(X0,sX,Y0,sY)

print "\n This should be good"
raw_input()
```

Comment: Do you need help getting rid of the divide by zero errors or do you want help simplifying the code?  If you want both, you should separate them into two different questions.

Comment: Have you tried hand-solving one of the failing examples to see if you are in fact dividing by zero somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried using libraries that help you solve these sorts of problems. The SciPy and NumPy Libraries have some great resources for solving these kind of Mathematical Problems.

Comment: It is right that there are other great resources and I haven't take my time to use them, but I'm trying to use my limited knowledge and try to solved those questions on my own. And yes, my brother told me to ask in two separate questions because one was the zero division error and the other the simplification of the last code, I better make a little more of research and then I will come back with a proper question.